# what are the steps to use a variable in my widget with provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage, flutter-provider

I have this code in a method of a class

```
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);
    uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
      var progress = event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble();
    });
```

I'd like to use the variable `progress` in my widget and i want it to update in realtime

What are the steps to do it ? do i have to suscribe to the stream `uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen` ? Or can i just watch the `progress` variable ?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation from provider,its all explained there.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/provider